# How globally listen all forms changes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

There are a lot of reactive forms: FormGroup on the page.

I can subscribe on one of them. But I need to have global listener, that listen all forms and says, from which form data comes.

How to do that in Angular?

Should I merge observables from each formGroup? Or there is another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create nested form group ([doc](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups))